# KXD 706 dirt bike

Tags: engine, motorcycle, starting, kxd

My bike doesn’t have a battery & its jump started, it usually made a sound trying to turn on, got told to replace spark plug even with the noise. I left the bike for about 3/4 months… I’ve changed the spark plug & now there’s no noise what so ever even with the old spark… does anyone know what I need to do to fix it please?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the plug for spark (ie: pulled it out of the head, put the wire on it, grounded the sparkplug to the head, then kicked it over while checking the gap for spark)?